# Put increasing number before echo result array

Tags: php

Hi I want to loop through some items and output is like this:

```
"&product_url[1]=http://www.result1.com&product_url[2]=http://www.result2.com&product_url[3]=http://www.result3.com"
```

So loop through and put a increasing number in front of each items starting with 1.

Any idea?

```
// get order items details
$order_items = $order->get_items();

// loop through items in order
foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ) {
    $product_link = get_permalink($product_id)
    echo $product_link;
}
```

Comment: What about using a *counter*?

Comment: Thanks, I do not know how :-)

Comment: What is in `$product_link`?

Comment: I'd recommend googling "php counter tutorial" before making an SO question.. Always try to work it out yourself first, SO is a Q&A site. Not a tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
     // get order items details
    $counter = 1;
    $url = "";
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    // loop through items in order
    foreach ( $order_items as $order_item ) {
        $product_link = get_permalink($product_id)
        $url .= "&product_url[$counter]=" . $product_link;
        $counter ++;
    }
    echo $url; // <-- here you will have the url.
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the job!